# How does the 'Australian' keyboard layout differ to US?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, localization

As a geek in Australia, It had always been my understanding that all keyboards here were US keyboards.

What are the differences, (if any) between selecting the Australian keyboard layout, from the US?

Comment: Did you try both and compared?

Comment: I don't have ubuntu installed, asking for a friend. That said, I'm looking for an authoritative answer, and I've tried and failed to view the source.

Comment: An an aussie, I don't believe there is any difference. I have both US made IBM keyboards & Australian made IBM (from long ago yes), and they have identical keyboard layout... I personally prefer the US because of the feel of their model M keyboards, so my aussie made keyboards (*whilst good quality*) are unused/unloved :(

Comment: Identical layout, means those keyboards are US layout. I'm trying to work out why Ubuntu goes to the effort of listing them separately (which I'm not honestly sure it does, friend may have misread Austrian...) or they may have been aliased, to make it easier for users to pick the correct layout if uninformed. I've tried looking at x11 sources online.

Comment: They are both Australian layout (though the US keyboard keys can be removed & re-ordered to any layout you prefer).  They both came in what was the "*Australian*" layout, which was identical to the US layout was my point.  The IBM documentation lists the same layout for Australia and the US (IBM PC Technical manual, IBM PC AT Technical Manual, IBM PS/2 Technical Manual etc... )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[English (Australian)](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config/-/blob/master/symbols/au) is an alias to English (US).

From : `xkeyboard-config/-/blob/master/symbols/au`

```
//
// Default Australian is the same as American
//
default partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {
    include "us(basic)"

    name[Group1]= "English (Australian)";
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There do not seem to be any differences.
However, some software chooses the spelling based on your keyboard layout (which for me most of the time is annoying). So, this may lead to different spelling dictionaries being used.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Despite `au` being an alias for `us` (as noted by Gunnar Hjalmarsson), importantly it doesn't inherit any of the layout variants (like Dvorak).

For example, `localectl list-x11-keymap-variants au` shows no entries on Pop!_OS 22.04. This means that I couldn't enable Dvorak at the login screen while set to the `au` layout.

Comment: This is a Ubuntu site and Pop OS is not Ubuntu. Do you know that works in Ubuntu?

Comment: If you want Dvorak, then configure English (Dvorak) — `us+dvorak`. You can have one layout on the login screen and another in the session. (@David: Ubuntu uses the same `xkb-data` package.)